# Extract words from a doc/docx file c#

Tags: c#, list, ms-word, office-interop

I want to extract all the words from a Word file (doc/docx) and put them into a list. It seems like microsoft.Office.Interop works just if i want to extract paragraphs and add them into a list.

```
List<string> data = new List<string>();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new 
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

Document doc = app.Documents.Open(dlg.FileName);

foreach (Paragraph objParagraph in doc.Paragraphs)
  data.Add(objParagraph.Range.Text.Trim());

((_Document)doc).Close();
((_Application)app).Quit();`
```

I also found the way to extract word by word but it didn't works with big document because of the loop that generates an exception.

```
`Dictionary<int, string> motRap = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Document document = application.Documents.Open("C:/Users/Titri/Desktop/test/test/bin/Debug/po.txt");

    // Loop through all words in the document.
    int count = document.Words.Count;
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        string text = document.Words[i].Text;
        motRap.Add(i, text);

    }
    // Close word.
    application.Quit();`
```

So my question is, if there is a way to extract words from a big word file. I think that Microsoft.Office.Interop is not the good tool to extract from a big file.
Sorry my english is not good.

Comment: Have you done any research on this?  This seems like a question that would've been asked before.

Comment: Yes it's been like 4 days that i do research on this. I find the way to extract words from a txt file, i found also a way to extract from a docx file but this way don't work for big file . So that's why I ask here.

Comment: I think you should take a look at [ask].  You need to show evidence of your research, i.e. in the form of links, etc., when you're asking a question that has probably been asked many times before.  Explain specifically how your research failed to help you find the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question. I didn't add the fact that I know how to extract word by word from a txt file because i don't think it's relevant for this topic.

Answer (score 1):

The object inside a paragraph is called [`Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278312.aspx), though I don't know whether or not this is available in Interop. To enhance your experience performancewise, I would suggest you switch to using `OpenXmlSdk`, in case you have to process a large amount of documents.

If you want to stick to Interop, why don't you just split each paragraph into an array (delimiter obviously space) and add all the words after that?

Comment: OpenXmlSdk allow us to manipulate  Doc files ? Because I thought that it was just for Open XML documents

Comment: Was not sure if you really needed them as you specified both. You are right indeed, OpenXmlSdk is for the OpenXml standard only. Otherwise, have a look at Aspose.Words, it is available as a nuget-package. It allows you to use both formats.

Comment: Yes i specified both because it depends of which version of Word the user will use because Word saves the file to doc or docx format but the more common is doc format.